# How to install Network Connect in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu

I want to install Juniper Network Connect in a virtual Xubuntu host, but...

If I go to the site of Juniper, the product "Network Connect" seems to be unavailable.

Searching in the web, I only found some .exe (for Windows), but anything for Unix.

Maybe I miss something, any suggest?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you could expand this question by going into the "Why?" It's possible that if we knew what you were trying to accomplish we could provide you with a functional solution. To be clear I'm asking "Why do you want to Install Juniper Network Connect under xubuntu?"